# User menu page visible to the author user (uid)

Tags: hooks

The view module has a great function when set a menu tab with contextual filter user:uid, so the user that is author of that node will be able to see the content. Lets say for an example the flag module has a view bookmarks, so when a user choose some node to follow/flag it will be available in his user/%/bookmarks.

How can I do this with custom code?
I have my code here as a test:

```
<?php
function mymodule_menu() {


    $items = array();   

    $items['user/%/add-news'] = array(
        'title' => 'Hello World',
        'page callback' => 'mymodule_user_news',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );

    return $items;
}

function mymodule_user_news() {
        return 'Hello world';
}
```

This "Hello World" everybody can see it. Of course, because I'm using 
`'access arguments' => array('access content'),`

How can I set this page to be visible only for user author?

I'm planning to add here a form, so the user can fill the form and send it to the administrator of the website.

Oh, by the way when I set a link only visible to the author user I use this 
 echo l(t("Profile edit"), 'user/' . $GLOBALS['user']->uid . '/edit');

How can I use the $GLOBALS['user']->uid in a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Access arguments](https://drupal.org/node/553368)

> Understanding access arguments in Drupal's menu system can be a little
>   confusing, but they are really quite simple. Let's take this example
>   and work through the arguments.
>
> ```
> <?php
>   $items['foo/bar/user'] = array(
>     'title' => 'Foobar',
>     'description' => 'List, add, and edit Foobars.',
>     'page callback' => 'foo_bar_function',
>     'access callback' => 'user_access',
>     'access arguments' => array('administer users'),
>   );
> ?>
> ```
>
> Permissions Arguments, array('this_permission') Here access arguments
>   is the key for an array that contains one item administer users. This
>   means that the current user must have permission to administer users
>   in order to access the page. Which page? Notice the first line gives
>   the path to $item. The path is 'foo/bar/user'.
>
> In this example, 'administer users' is the string that drupal uses to
>   reference permissions. If you go to the permissions page (Administer
>
> > > User Management >> Permissions), you can see a list of strings you might use for access arguments. Each permission can be used by your
> > >       module.